# Exception in Linux Server (Convert Text to PDF - IText)

Tags: java, linux, exception, pdf, itext

I made a class of converting text files to PDF using iText.

In my localhost it worked perfectly, but on my linux server I'm having is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:229)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.seek(MappedRandomAccessFile.java:157)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.seek(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:354)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.getAllNames(TrueTypeFont.java:588)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(TrueTypeFont.java:662)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.<init>(TrueTypeFontUnicode.java:94)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:688)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:606)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:441)
    at com.ford.fc.frc.render.renderers.wholesaletopdf.WSLtoPDFWriter.createBaseFont(WSLtoPDFWriter.java:170)
    at com.ford.fc.frc.render.renderers.wholesaletopdf.WSLtoPDFConverter.setFont(WSLtoPDFConverter.java:269)
    at com.ford.fc.frc.render.renderers.wholesaletopdf.WSLtoPDFRenderer.loadFontConverter(WSLtoPDFRenderer.java:74)
    at com.ford.fc.frc.render.renderers.wholesaletopdf.WSLtoPDFRenderer.render(WSLtoPDFRenderer.java:46)
    at com.ford.fc.frc.render.domain.AbstractRenderer.doRenderer(AbstractRenderer.java:96)
    at com.ford.fc.frc.render.converters.PDFConverter.converter(PDFConverter.java:43)
```

This is my code:

```
    public void createBaseFont(int fontNum, String fontName) {
    try {
        if (fontNum < 10) {
            bf[fontNum] = BaseFont.createFont(fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        }
    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        de.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        bf[fontNum] = getCourierBoldDefaultFont();
    }
}


    public void createCourierFont(final String pathCourierFont) {
    try {
        BaseFont courierBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont(pathCourierFont, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        this.courierFont = new Font(courierBaseFont, 7f);
    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        de.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        this.courierFont = new Font(getCourierBoldDefaultFont(), 7f);
    }
}
```

Has anyone been through this? I thank you to help:

Comment: Do `courierBaseFont` and `getCourierBoldDefaultFont` ultimately return one of the defined FontFamily values? At a guess, iText seems unable to locate or load its default font set.

Comment: So how to load is correct, in my view and the tests that I realized, it seems to me to make FTP the source to the linux something happened, because Windows (localhost), it works perfectly, someone could tell me how I I pass a file (. ttf) to linux (ASCII or Binary)

I'm loading a courbd.ttf font and  is located in a one directory in my server, in my case I pass the path of this directory to create the font

Comment: The problem is caused by the font. One of the possible causes could be that the font file got corrupted when copying it: e.g. it's no longer a binary file, it has been truncated,...